# Help Understanding Solution? (Putnam and Beyond)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

From Putnam and Beyond:

> Proofs (Question 10:)
>
> Let $n>1$ be an arbitrary real number and let $k$ be the number of
>   positive prime numbers less than or equal to $n$. Select $k + 1$ positive
>   integers such that none of them divides the product of all the others.
>   Prove that there exists a number among the chosen $k + 1$ that is bigger
>   than $n$.
>
> Assume the contrary. Our chosen numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{k+1}$ must have a
>   total of at most $k$ distinct prime factors (the primes less than or
>   equal to $n$). Let $o_p(q)$ denote the highest value of $d$ such that $p^d\mid q$.
>   Also, let $a = a_1a_2\dots a_{k+1}$ be the product of the numbers. Then for
>   each prime $p$, $o_p(a) = \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} o_p(a_i)$, and it follows

Here's the part onwards that I do not understand: Specifically, what does it mean by hostile value?

> that there can be at most one hostile value of $i$ for which
>   $o_p(a_i)>o_{p}(a)/2$. Because there are at most $k$ primes that divide $a$, there
>   is some $i$ that is not hostile for any such prime. Then $2o_p(a_i)\le o_p(a)$, so $o_p(a_i) \le o_p(a/a_i)$ for each prime $p$ dividing $a$. This implies
>   that $a_i$ divides $a/a_i$, which contradicts the fact that the $a_i$ does not
>   divide the product of the other $a_j$’s. Hence our assumption was false,
>   and the conclusion follows.

Question is page 16 of the pdf while answer is on 367 of the pdf.

Thanks.

PS Can someone help me tag it here
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contest-math

When I put 'contest-math' it does not recognize the existing tag and says its new.

Comment: Please learn some TeX, as your question is almost unreadable without it. For example, instead of a1, write a_1, and put dollar signs around it, and you get $a_1$.

Comment: I think that I guessed correctly at subscripts and superscripts, but you should check my translation.

Comment: Doesn't this book also provide solutions. (Solution to your question on page 367)

Comment: @Artin: The OP’s question is about the language of the solution.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson: Thanks, for notice. I will use Tex next time.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks for turning it into TeX, just two small mistakes which I corrected.

Comment: Please remove the link to the book. It is not yet freely distributable, legally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence in which the term *hostile value of i* is used is intended to define the term: a hostile value of $i$ is one such that $o_p(a_i)>o_p(a)/2$. If there were distinct $i$ and $j$ such that $o_p(a_i)>o_p(a)/2$ and $o_p(a_j)>o_p(a)/2$, then $o_p(a) = \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} o_p(a_i)>o_p(a)$, so there is at most one such ‘hostile’ $i$. (I usually use the term ‘bad’ as a temporary descriptive term in such situations.) We therefore have $o_p(a_j)\le o_p(a)/2$ for $j\ne i$ and hence $2o_p(a_j)\le o_p(a)$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.